# Read parquet files in Spark with pattern matching

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

I'm running Spark 1.3.0 and want to read a number of parquet files based on pattern matching. the parquet files are basically the underlying files of a Hive DB and I want to read some of the files (across different folders) only. the folder structure is

```
hdfs://myhost:8020/user/hive/warehouse/db/blogs/some/meta/files/
hdfs://myhost:8020/user/hive/warehouse/db/blogs/yymmdd=20160101/01/file1.parq         
hdfs://myhost:8020/user/hive/warehouse/db/blogs/yymmdd=20160101/02/file2.parq
hdfs://myhost:8020/user/hive/warehouse/db/blogs/yymmdd=20160103/01/file3.parq
```

Something like

```
val v1 = sqlContext.parquetFile("hdfs://myhost:8020/user/hive/warehouse/db/blogs/yymmdd={[0-9]*}")
```

I want to ignore the meta files and load only the parquet files inside the date folders. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

you can use wildcard in parquet like so (works on 1.5 didn't test on 1.3):

```
val v1 = sqlContext.parquetFile("hdfs://myhost:8020/user/hive/warehouse/db/blogs/yymmdd*")
```

another thing you can do in case that doesn't work is to create external table using hive with partition by yymmdd and read parquet from that table using:

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
sqlContext.sql("SELECT FROM ...")
```

you can't use regular expression.

also I think you folder structure is problematic. it should be
hdfs://myhost:8020/user/hive/warehouse/db/blogs/yymmdd=150204/
or
hdfs://myhost:8020/user/hive/warehouse/db/blogs/yymmdd=150204/part=01
and not:
hdfs://myhost:8020/user/hive/warehouse/db/blogs/yymmdd=150204/1

because they way you use it I think you will have troubles using the folder names (yymmdd) as partition because the files are not directly under it